# Problem with stereo and monocular calibration on openni_kinect

Tags: ros, calibration, kinect, stereo-calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, Im trying to get my kinect stereo calibrate so I was following this tutorial:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration#Before_Starting

but when I try $ rostopic list, it doesn't show any of the /my_stereo.../   and when I tried

rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 right:=/my_stereo/right/image_raw left:=/my_stereo/left/image_raw right_camera:=/my_stereo/right left_camera:=/my_stereo/left

I got:
"Waiting for service /my_stereo/left/set_camera_info ...
Service not found
Waiting for service /my_stereo/right/set_camera_info ...
Service not found"

I also tried the Monocular Camera calibration on:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration
and got the same problem
"Waiting for service /camera/set_camera_info ...
Service not found"
with $ rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/camera/image_raw camera:=/camera

What im doing wrong? What should I do?
Im working on ubuntu 12.04 and ros fuerte.

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40325/problem-with-stereo-and-monocular-calibration-on-openni_kinect/) by [Fer Nunez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2960/fer-nunez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The kinect is not a (traditional) stereo camera, so the stereo calibration will not work. There is a [wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration) which details how to calibrate a kinect properly.

There isn't quite enough information to figure out why the set_camera_info service can't be found. Could you edit your question to add the exact command you're using the launch the camera driver?

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0